# 5k changes when using git init

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Every time I use the `git init` command for my project in VS Code, it suggests 5k+ changes in source control.

Do I need to reinstall something? Nothing I have searched regarding this problem seems to be working. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Could you maybe give some of the actual evidence you're looking at, rather than just characterizing it?

Comment: Hi 777pretty, welcome to stackoverflow. I think this issue is related to where you have initialized your git. I think you have initialized your git where many folders are included. Create a new folder with nothing else in there. do "git init" and you should only see your actual changes. In your case I think you have done a git init where many other folder and system directories or virtual environments exist. Whenever these system files change, they are automatically included in your git. i.e if I do a git init in the windows folder, even if I only change one file, there will be 1000+ changes.

Comment: Why are you running `git init` more than once? If you're creating a repository in an existing directory where no repository exists you can expect that every file will show up as new. Is that what you're seeing? Please read [ask].

Comment: Are you running the command in an empty project or a one which already has some files? Also, are you inside the right directory?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and turns out I was tracking my home directory without knowing, probably by accident. I just deleted the .git folder in home directory and the problem was solved.

```
$ rm -rf .git
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment you may have initialized your git in a folder containing many other files. @vonc has already explained the issue. Try the following:

Close visual studio code
On the command prompt (windows) or terminal (osx) go to the folder where your project is
i.e if your project folder is

`c:\users\someuser\project\racecar_project`

Make sure you are *inside the folder* `racecar_project`

Initialize your git by issuing `git init` .

Next you may want to add the files to your git repo by:

```
git add --all
```

Now open visual studio code and go to your folder.
Open gitlense if that is one of the plugins you are using and change a few files, the change should only show the files you have changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a `.gitignore` file, and put it in your root folder.

The purpose of `.gitignore` files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by GIT remain untracked.

I use Visual Studio Code, I'm sure it's all the same. I created a new file named .gitignore in my root folder.

This is an example of what I put to ignore `node_modules`:

[image: .gitignore commands]

My source:
https://coursework.vschool.io/create-a-gitignore/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nodejs/react/meteor project, you must know that it will create .node_module/local folder for you under which all modules are saved.

Then you should

```
create .gitignore file
```

file under your project folder.

add below line to it:

1. If you have node/react project and you can see untracked files from node_module folder

   ```
   node_modules
   ```
2. If you have meteor project and you can see untracked files from local folder of .meteor folder.

   ```
   local
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It should be 5K+ new files to add, if you truly initialize a new repository in a non-empty folder.

In that case, you need to add a `.gitignore` file at the root folder of your initialized repo, and add patterns to ignore what you don't need.
That is assuming that root folder is the one for your existing project (and not `/` or `$HOME`, which would include way too many file, unrelated to your project)

Answer (score 0):

Its because git is tracking for all the files even which are present in node_modules directory.
You have to create a .gitignore file and add node_modules/ inside it to tell git not to track them as they are third party code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case find a folder called .git on C:\Users\xxxxx >>> here check that there's no hidden folders, then just delete that folder, all 5k changes will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Mac**,

Make sure you go to the Home Folder and delete everything from there.

Mine has fixed this way

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem.

1. In vscode Right click on "SOURCE CONTROL" at the top of open source control panel, then make sure "Source Control" is selected.
2. Open the drop down "SOURCE CONTROL REPOSITORIES" next to the top of the source control panel and right click on the repo which is incorrectly set and select "Close Repository".

[Here is a visual of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6KVK.jpg)